# Removing unwanted lines from image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm currently working on a project which reads an image, applies a number of filters, with the purpose of being able to place a bounding rect around regions of interest.

I have an image of handwritten text on lined paper as my input:

```
string imageLocation = "loctation of image file";
src = imread(imageLocation, 1);
```

[image: Inputted image]

I then convert the image to gray scale and apply adaptive thresholding:

```
cvtColor(src, newsrc, CV_BGR2GRAY);
adaptiveThreshold(~newsrc, dst, 255, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 15, -2);
```

[image: Applied adaptive thresholding]

I then use morphological operations to attempt to eliminate the horizontal lines from the image:

```
Mat horizontal = dst.clone();

int horizontalSize = dst.cols / 30;
Mat horizontalStructure = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(horizontalSize,1));

erode(horizontal, horizontal, horizontalStructure, Point(-1, -1));
dilate(horizontal, horizontal, horizontalStructure, Point(-1, -1));

cv::resize(horizontal, horizontal, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5, CV_INTER_CUBIC);
imshow("horizontal", horizontal);
```

Which produces the following (so far so good): 
[image: Input image horizontal line seperation]

I then try to use the same erode & dilate methods to figure out the vertical:

```
int verticalsize = dst.rows / 30;
Mat verticalStructure = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size( 1,verticalsize));

erode(vertical, vertical, verticalStructure, Point(-1, -1));
dilate(vertical, vertical, verticalStructure, Point(-1, -1));

cv::resize(vertical, vertical, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5, CV_INTER_CUBIC);
imshow("vertical", vertical);
```

I'm following OpenCV's example, which can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dee/tutorial_moprh_lines_detection.html)

But, the output i'm getting for the vertical is: 
[image: Vertical output]

My question is, how would I go about removing these horizontal lines from the image.

Sorry for the lengthy question (I wanted to explain as much as I could) and thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: What do you mean by trying to figure out the vertical?

Comment: I've posted a link to an OpenCV example, and they use morphological operations in order to extract the horizontal and vertical lines to seperate the text from the horizontal lines.

Comment: I cant see where was `Mat vertical` declared and initialized? are you sure about it?

Comment: I have intitaliased I just didnt include sorry. But:
`Mat vertical = dst.clone();`

Comment: Have you tried substracting image3 from image2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make this work in frequency domain like here:

http://lifeandprejudice.blogspot.ru/2012/07/activity-6-enhancement-in-frequency_25.html

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/fourier_transforms/fourier.html

Working with FFT is very effective in adding/removing regilar grids from image.

Comment: I'll take a look now. If possible, are you able to check the example I linked in the question to see how thats done. I'd like to know where I'm actually going wrong

Comment: Your vertical size of erosion kernel is too large, you really not have such thick elements in your image.

Comment: So would it be a case of playing around with the `verticalsize = dist.cols() / 30`